# adjust position of ui droppable with dyanmic variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make it so that when one div is dropped upon the target div, it sticks to the top left.. and when the next one is dropped on the same target then it's still at the top left and also offset by the height of the first dropped div.

Once I learned that offset works differently in newer versions of jquery UI I thought I had it.. but at this point I'm at a loss.

```
var offsetValue = Number(0);
var cardHeight = parseInt($(".card").height());
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('.card').draggable({
            revert: true,
            disabled: false
        });
        $('.target').droppable({
            hoverClass: 'hovered',
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                if (ui.draggable.attr('id') == $(this).attr('id').substr(0, 7)) {
                    totalAttempts++;
                    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
                    ui.draggable.position({
                        of: $(this),
                        my: 'left top',
                        at: 'left top+offsetValue',
                        collision:'none'
                    });
                    offsetValue = offsetValue+cardHeight;
```

Is this not possible?

```js
$('#endGame').hide();
var totalCards = 3;
var totalAttempts = 0;
var offsetValue = Number(0);
var cardHeight = parseInt($(".card").height());
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(function() {
  $('.card').draggable({
   revert: true,
   disabled: false
  });
  $('.target').droppable({
   hoverClass: 'hovered',
   drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.draggable.attr('id') == $(this).attr('id').substr(0, 7)) {
     totalAttempts++;
     ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
     ui.draggable.position({
      of: $(this),
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left top+offsetValue',
      collision:'none'
     });
     offsetValue = offsetValue+cardHeight;
     console.log(offsetValue);
     //$(this).removeClass('target');
     //$(this).addClass('targetDisabled');
     ui.draggable.removeClass('card');
     ui.draggable.addClass('cardCorrect');
     ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
     if (totalAttempts == totalCards) {
      console.log("done!");
      $('#endGame').show();
      $( "#endGame" ).removeClass('endDisabled');
      $( "#endGame" ).addClass('endEnabled');
     }
    }
   }
  });
  var randomDivs = $("div.card").get().sort(function() {
   return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
  });
  $(randomDivs).appendTo(randomDivs[0].parentNode).show();
 });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
 width:892px;
 margin:0 auto
}

.card, .cardCorrect, .tdTargets, .target, .targetDisabled {
  width:280px; /*Largest Possible: 384px*/
 }
 
 .card, .cardCorrect {
  height: 50px;
 }
 
 .tdTargets, .target {
  height: 550px;
 }
.card {
 background-color:#c8e7d6;
 padding:3px;
 margin:10px;
 -webkit-user-select:none;
 -moz-user-select:none;
 -ms-user-select:none;
 user-select:none;
 cursor:move;
 vertical-align:top;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 border-radius:5px
}

.cardCorrect {
 background-color:transparent;
 padding:3px;
 margin:10px;
 -webkit-user-select:text;
 -moz-user-select:text;
 -ms-user-select:text;
 user-select:text;
 cursor:default
}

#actTab {
 border-collapse:collapse
}

#actTab td {
 vertical-align:top;
 border:1px solid #000;
 text-align:left;
 padding:4px
}

#actTab th {
 vertical-align:top;
 border:1px solid #000;
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#2b6a47;
 padding:4px;
 font-weight:400
}

.tdLabels {
 width:70px
}

.target {
 border:1px dotted #000;
 padding:3px
}

.hovered {
 background:#eeecdc
}

.targetDisabled {
 border:1px dotted #fff;
 padding:3px
}

#gameTable {
 float:left;
}

#options {
 float:right;
}

#endWrapper {
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:20px;
 
}
.endDisabled {
 color:#fff;
}

.endEnabled {
 color:#000;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 

 <div id="gameTable">
    <table id="actTab" width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Label A</td>
    <th>Label B</td>
    <th>Label C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdTargets"><div class="target" id="answer1target"></div></td>
    <td class="tdTargets"><div class="target" id="answer2target"></div></td>
    <td class="tdTargets"><div class="target" id="answer3target"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table><div id="options">
  <div class="card" id="answer2">
   Option 1
  </div>

  <div class="card" id="answer2">
   Option 2
  </div>

  <div class="card" id="answer2">
   Option 3
  </div>
 </div><!--end #options-->
 </div><!--end #gameTable-->

 <div style="clear:both"></div><!--Do not delete: using brute force so the remainder of the layout plays nice-->

 <div id="endWrapper">
  <div class="endDisabled" id="endGame">
   Complete!
  </div>&nbsp; <!--end #endGame: Non linebreaking space here to keep the items on the page from jumping when #endGame is enabled-->
 </div><!--end #endWrapper-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is at the CSS add more margin to the bottom of each element

```
.card, .cardCorrect, .tdTargets, .target, .targetDisabled {
        width:280px; /*Largest Possible: 384px*/
    margin-bottom:25px;
    }
```